# How to get Webstorm 11 to recognize ES2015 javascript in HTML script tags

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, syntax-highlighting, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've been having trouble getting WebStorm 11 to recognize/highlight/parse ES6/ES2015 javascript when it's inside script tags in regular HTML. Can't find a setting that seems to apply to this. Thanks in advance for your time.

For example, the following js is inside a script tag. You'll notice that WebStorm thinks that a whole bunch of things are broken with it, but it executes just fine.

[image: this code parses and executes fine in babel but is not recognized by WebStorm]

Comment: Fixed a similar situation by changing the Javascript Language Version to ES6 under settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Javascript

Answer (score 19):

Using
`<script type="text/ecmascript-6">` rather than `<script type="text/javascript">` should help you.

[Issue on JetBrans YouTrack on the topic](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16873).

#### UPD:

It looks like a WebStorm bug (tested on the latest release):

```
  var a = (d) => {}; //OK
  a.v('c', (d) => {}); // OK
  class Test {
    doSmth(){
      a.sh('ff', (d) => {});
      //            ^^^^^^ , or ) expected when in <script>
      //            100% OK when in a js file
    }
  }
```

I think you could contact JetBrains support, probably they will fix it.

But anyways, I do not think [it's a good practice to have JS in your HTML](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting) and, moreover, ES6 which is not yet commonly supported.

#### UPD 2:

As posted in comments by, [zigomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260138/zigomir), you might want to use `type="text/babel"` instead of `type="text/ecmascript-6"` in `.vue` files or otherwise linting wouldn't work.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still see yellow backgrounds and other errors on error-free code.

Comment: @CarlYoungblood Could you please share some code snippet and the text of the error you're getting?

Comment: I'd like to post a screen capture but I don't think it's allowed here. For example, if I create an arrow function like this:

arg => { return arg - 1 }

There is a squiggly red line under arg and hovering over it says "unresolved variable or type arg" even though the code parses and executes just fine.

Comment: I just added a screenshot to the original problem demonstrating it.

Comment: Thanks @strrife. This is actually standard practice for Google Polymer Elements. Gulp build steps strip, concatenate, transpile and minify the js later.

Comment: @CarlYoungblood oh, sorry, I'm not quite familiar with it. Anyway, I think you might want to send a bug report to JetBrains. Good luck with that!

Comment: Thanks @strrife. I submitted a bug report.

Comment: Update 2016-02-21 Google Chrome no longer executes a script block with `type="text/ecmascript-6`, be careful ! @CarlYoungblood please link us to the bug report so we can upvote it !

Comment: I had problems with `type="text/ecmascript-6" within `.vue` files (lint-ing wouldn't work) and I'm now using `type="text/babel"` which works fine.