# Inline ES6 Scripts in Intellij IDEA and WebStorm without type attribute

Tags: intellij-idea, ecmascript-6, syntax-highlighting, webstorm, polymer-1.0

Is there any way to make IntelliJ IDEA to support ECMAScript-6 syntax in inlined `<script>...</script>` tags without specifying `<script type="text/ecmascript-6">`, which is not supported in newer Chrome browser.

It is annoying especially with arrow-functions, because it messes up the indentation and prevents auto indentation.

I'm massively using it in a recent polymer project and I definitely want it to be inline scripts, even though it is being separated upon build-time.

This question is closely related to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722779/how-to-get-webstorm-11-to-recognize-es2015-javascript-in-html-script-tags).

Tried it in with

```
WebStorm 2016.1.3
Build #WS-145.1616, built on May 27, 2016
```

and

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1
Build #IU-145.258, built on March 17, 2016
```

[image: Arrow functions not recognized properly in WebStorm]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WEB-16444](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16444) is fixed in WebStorm 2016.2

Answer (score 0):

A temporary work around for this behavior, but not a complete solution for the problem in IDEA / WebStorm is to use the `<script type="text/ecmascript-6">` tag and filter it out by crisper, which is part of the default build process in a lot of polymer projects. For this it is necessary to add a line to `crisper/index.js` at the `inlineScriptFinder()` method add

```
pred.hasAttrValue('type', 'text/ecmascript-6')
```

This does only work if the dev-build and dist-build is using crisper in its build pipeline.

I would like to have a solution without that work around.

**update**
I just have seen, that it is already present in latest release of crisper (see [commit](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/crisper/commit/1d787960397076eba9a1050e5edfc9be7ca6179e))